# JDK21 Manage Virtual Thread Executor Service

Tags: java, openjdk-21

I know that

> The JVM maintains a pool of platform threads, created and maintained
> by a dedicated ForkJoinPool. Initially, the number of platform threads
> equals the number of CPU cores, and it cannot increase more than 256.

but i don't find how to config number of thread for this pool.

Comment: Based on [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-15BDB995-028A-45A7-B6E2-9BA15C2E0501), I doubt there is a number.  You aren’t supposed to try limit virtual threads based on any count, from what I can tell.  And you definitely should not use thread pools with virtual threads;  virtual threads are already inherently managed like a pool.

Comment: For reference, the OP's quote seems to be from https://blog.rockthejvm.com/ultimate-guide-to-java-virtual-threads/

Comment: @VGR I just want to manage platform thread not virtual thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to read the official documentation of [`java.lang.Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html):

> **Implementation Note:**
>
> In the JDK Reference Implementation, the virtual thread scheduler may be configured with the following system properties:
>
> | System properties | System property Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.parallelism` | The number of platform threads available for scheduling virtual threads. It defaults to the number of available processors. |
> | `jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.maxPoolSize` | The maximum number of platform threads available to the scheduler. It defaults to 256. |

That means that you can change the maximum pool size when starting your application with

```
java -Djdk.virtualThreadScheduler.maxPoolSize=512 other arguments ...
```